# apt-get broken trust chain while updating

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

This morning I restarted my server and discovered an issue while doing `apt-get update`:

```
Err:1 http://hwraid.le-vert.net/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'hwraid.le-vert.net'
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                    
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease      
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease     
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
  Could not resolve 'repo.mongodb.org'
Err:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve host: download.docker.com
Err:10 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve host: deb.nodesource.com
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: download.docker.com
W: Failed to fetch http://hwraid.le-vert.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'hwraid.le-vert.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.2/InRelease  Could not resolve 'repo.mongodb.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: deb.nodesource.com
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Now this isnt a big deal, I know the common issues and fixes for `apt` and attempted a few of them, however during my troubleshooting I came across something interesting, whenever I run the update in the `syslog` I get the following:

```
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: validating _http._tcp.us.archive.ubuntu.com/SRV: bad cache hit (com/DS)
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: broken trust chain resolving '_http._tcp.us.archive.ubuntu.com/SRV/IN': 10.0.2.1#53
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: validating _http._tcp.repo.mongodb.org/SRV: bad cache hit (org/DS)
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: broken trust chain resolving '_http._tcp.repo.mongodb.org/SRV/IN': 10.0.2.1#53
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: validating _http._tcp.ppa.launchpad.net/SRV: bad cache hit (net/DS)
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: broken trust chain resolving '_http._tcp.ppa.launchpad.net/SRV/IN': 10.0.2.1#53
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: validating _http._tcp.hwraid.le-vert.net/SRV: bad cache hit (net/DS)
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: broken trust chain resolving '_http._tcp.hwraid.le-vert.net/SRV/IN': 10.0.2.1#53
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: validating _http._tcp.security.ubuntu.com/SRV: bad cache hit (com/DS)
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: broken trust chain resolving '_http._tcp.security.ubuntu.com/SRV/IN': 10.0.2.1#53
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: validating deb.nodesource.com/A: bad cache hit (com/DS)
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: broken trust chain resolving 'deb.nodesource.com/A/IN': 10.0.2.1#53
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: validating download.docker.com/CNAME: bad cache hit (com/DS)
Dec 10 09:11:37 magic named[2715]: broken trust chain resolving 'download.docker.com/A/IN': 10.0.2.1#53
...
```

I have no idea what this means and Googleing it hasnt helped me thus far, what does this mean and how can I fix it successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "could not resolve" suggests that you're having a DNS resolution issue, which in turn causes the broken trust chain.  I would examine your DNS settings - doing a simple `ping` to a domain name (not an IP address) should confirm this theory.  Try `ping us.archive.ubuntu.com` for instance.

Comment: I was able to fix it with a `sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf` seems like when i rebooted it wiped my resolv.conf?